# Pop!_OS Green Screen Crash & Then Restart

Tags: linux, drivers, amd-graphics-card

I recently built a machine & installed Pop!_OS. Increasingly, my monitors will go green & the machine will restart.

My hardware:

- CPU: AMD® Ryzen 7 3800x 8-core processor × 16
- GPU: AMD® Radeon rx 5600 xt
- BIOS: F31O
- RAM: Hyperx Fury (2x32gb) 64gb 3466mhz (XMP enabled, Profile 1)
- OS: Pop!_OS 20.10

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` outputs:

```
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev ca)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I've looked in the following, however, I don't even know what I need to be looking for to diagnose:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/dmesg`

I'm using the stock Ryzen Cooler, but I've not overclocked anything and none of my temps seem to go above 55°C

My question(s)

- Is my issue GPU related? What drivers should I use and/or do I need to update anything?
- Should I be using amdgpu as a driver?
- What steps should I take to start getting the info to better diagnose?

Comment: Is it worth adding nomodeset and noacpi acpi=off as grub boot options?